# Add an image at the bottom of each beamer frame

Tags: beamer, graphics, vertical-alignment

For my presentation in `beamer`, I need to put a full textwidth image at the bottom of each frame. Currently, I am doing that manually:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title}
  \vskip0pt plus 1filll
  \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=1cm]{../Preambles/mc_banner.png}}
\end{frame}
```

But is it possible to edit the preamble so that this banner is place at the bottom of each frame?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install the `background` or `background canvas` templates to include your image; I placed it inside a `\raisebox` hiding its height and depth so you can move it freely.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
  \raisebox{-\paperheight}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \makebox[\paperwidth][c]{%
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]